# How to replace an image displayed in an mvc app on iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have a simple mvc app deployed on iis that just displays an image.
I wanted to change the image that is shown but when I replaced the image in the content folder with another one that has the same name it didn't work.
Do I have to recompile?

Comment: Are you sure your browser is not simply caching the image?

Comment: I've cleared the cache but it still doesnt display the new image that is on iis.

Comment: Also I get the 200 status on the image so I guess its cached on the server somewhere.